# Where can I take a selfie with kangaroos in Australia?

Tags: australia, nature-and-wildlife

I see a lot of people doing this. I believe this is not safe, isn't it?

Where can I do this?

Comment: I just re-defined what I want to ask

Comment: Enough places that you'll find somewhere if there for a few weeks. (My daughter used to walk to work past "wild one". Tame ones cdan be very tame albeit often aloof. DO NOT accept a challenge to box :-) - big red makes Thai kick boxers look weak :-).

Comment: First watch this movie: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0257568/?ref_=nv_sr_1
and then consider whether you actually want to take a selfie with a kangaroo.

Comment: Green screen + photoshop!

Comment: Until converted by a boomerang ...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Kangaroos are wild animals. While you will come across them if you are driving in rural areas, do not approach them. While most will simply run away, some may enter a more defensive posture especially if there are young (joeys) nearby.  A kick from an adult can kill a human (http://www.amazingaustralia.com.au/animals/kangaroo_attacks.htm).

Kangaroos can be mean vicious creatures. When I was growing up as a kid in Australia, we were cautioned away from getting anywhere near them.

The best and safest way to get a selfie with a kangaroo that isn't a cardboard cutout is to go to a zoo that has a petting zoo component. Instead of kangaroos, they often pick the smaller/friendlier cousin, the wallaby (http://animals.howstuffworks.com/mammals/wallaby-vs-kangaroo.htm).

This is just one of many petting zoos that have wallabies: [http://www.featherdale.com.au/#*=*](http://www.featherdale.com.au/#_=_)

Comment: Kangaroo attacks are very very very rare. No fatality has ever occurred except when the victim has provoked the kangaroo.

Comment: Deaths are rare as kangaroos are not carnivores / predators and thus will not fight to kill,  but  attacks with injuries are not uncommon.

Comment: Oh rubbish. When I was growing up as a kid in Australia I never heard anything of the sort. You won't get close enough for a two-shot as they will move away, but they are fairly approachable at most times. Try Healesville Sanctuary if you're going to Melbourne, or if you get as far as the Grampians try Zumsteins.

Comment: Oz government disagrees with you: https://www.ehp.qld.gov.au/wildlife/livingwith/kangaroos.html

Comment: Wild kangaroos will only attack if provoked. Most of the time they'll either run, or beg for food depending on where you find them.

Comment: @RoboKaren 1. That is the Queensland government, not the 'Oz government'. 2. I don't live in Queensland :-| 3. Governments frequently disagree with me: that doesn't make them right; but your citation supports my claims far more than it does yours.

Answer (score 20):

It depends on how close you intend on getting for your selfies.  If you insist on approaching closely, I would only do so in a controlled environment.  If you're willing to have your selfie with the kangaroos a dozen or more metres in the background, you'll be fine.

As to where you're able to do so, just about every major town or tourist location has some location where you can get close to kangaroos - patting or hand feeding, either of which would allow selfie opportunities.  Some examples include:

- Sydney has [Taronga Zoo](https://taronga.org.au/taronga-zoo) (free roaming kangaroo area) and [Featherdale Wildlife Park](http://www.featherdale.com.au/park-information/)
- [Melbourne](http://www.marukoalapark.com.au/)
- [Brisbane](http://www.koala.net/en/)
- [Cairns](http://www.cairnstropicalzoo.com.au/) and [Kuranda](http://www.koalagardens.com/)
- [Alice Springs](https://www.kangaroosanctuary.com/)
- [Even the Whitsundays](http://www.hamiltonisland.com.au/nature-and-wildlife/wildlife-hamilton-island)

Searching specifically for whereever you may be visiting would almost undoubtedly find somewhere, as all international airports and ports would have somewhere within an hour or less.

Of course, you could just go golfing.

[image: Mareeba Golf Course]

Mareeba Golf Course. Credit: [Sweetwater Lodge](http://sweetwaterlodge.com.au/kangaroo-spectators-at-mareeba-golf-club/)

[image: Yamba Golf Course]

Yamba Golf Course. Credit: [Shelley Street Beach House](http://www.stayz.com.au/accommodation/nsw/northern-rivers-byron-bay/angourie/138240)

[image: Anglesea Golf Course]

Anglesea Golf Course. Credit: [Anglesea Golf Club](http://www.angleseagolfclub.com.au/layouts/mp_standard/Template.aspx?page=Kangaroos)

Comment: If those are not your photos (and, come to think of it, even if they are), please credit the source.

Answer (score 6):

The [Cairns Tropical Zoo](http://www.cairnstropicalzoo.com.au/wildlife_displays.html) has a Kangaroo enclosure:

> Spend time in our kangaroo area. Around 60 tame Eastern Grey kangaroos spend their day meeting visitors, eating from your hand and lazing in the heat of the day.

I can confirm that they will let you get relatively close if they are in the right mood, but not necessarily for the kind of "hugging" selfie you'd take with a human.

Comment: The [Australia Zoo](https://www.australiazoo.com.au/our-animals/feed-the-animals/) outside Brisbane has a similar enclosure.  If they're willing to cooperate you might be able to get a picture of them eating out of your hand.

Answer (score 4):

The [Lone Pine Koala Sanctuary](http://www.koala.net/en/) in Brisbane also has a kangaroo enclosure where you can hand-feed kangaroos, including (according to their website) Red Kangaroos and Eastern Grey Kangaroos.  I visited many years ago and can confirm that they will eat out of your hand;  however, selfies were not a thing then, and so I didn't try to take one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are traveling to Melbourne, I recommend you visit Healesville Sanctuary, it's about an hour east of Melbourne, they have Kangaroo's they are quite used to people.

http://www.zoo.org.au/healesville/animals

Answer (score 2):

I went to the Featherdale Wildlife Park outside of Sydney when I was about 16. It was great and plenty of exotic(by my standards) animals running around that could be fed and touched. However, I don't recall any kangaroos that were free roaming in the park, I think they were all in enclosed spaces, but plenty of small wallabies running around like goons.

Answer (score 2):

Featherdale in Sydney has wallabies and possibly roos. Bonorong, just outside Hobart, has both. In fact, they give you a bag of food for them upon entry. They seem to be very people friendly and don't mind you petting them.

Answer (score 2):

Cleland Wildlife Park in Adelaide has tame Kangaroos for selfies.